# Gitlab CI gives 500, ERROR: relation "sessions" does not exist

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I upgraded Gitlab from 7.1.1 to 7.7.2 with the omnibus package.

After the upgrade I decided to give Gitlab CI a try and added the `ci_external_url` line to */etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb*, but when I browse to the defined URL I get a 500 error and the logs output the following:

```
Started GET "/" for 1.3.3.7 at 2015-02-04 09:14:35 +0200
Processing by ProjectsController#index as HTML
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "sessions" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"sessions"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"sessions"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

Redirected to 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "sessions" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"sessions"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"sessions"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
):
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:76:in `check_config'
```

I am running this on Debian 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you haven't migrated your database (`rake db:migrate`), or you have migrated and your code is using a database table that doesn't exist.

Try migrating to see if this solves your problem.

Update: for other people with the same issue, seems like the command for Gitlab is `gitlab-ci-rake db:migrate`

Comment: The documentation is a little messy for gitlab, but you were right:
gitlab-ci-rake db:migrate
 did the trick

Comment: Nice! So @Tebro, can you mark my answer as the correct solution please? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, just had to wait for the timer to run out ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the integrated information check `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production` the most helpful command in gitlab. It can highlight a lot of issues you can run into during an update. Beside regular permission issues it also identifies missing DB updates.

Beside this, we follow the [manual update guides](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/tree/master/doc/update) religiously since they contain every step we needed so far (we don't use omnibus).